# reading .dat file in python (Agilent 4294A Precision Impedance Analyzer)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to read a .dat file from an Agilent impedance analyzer. I keep getting the same error regardless of the method I try. Any ideas how to get around this issue?

Thanks in advance.

```
# import csv

# Method 1
# with open("RP.dat") as infile, open("outfile.csv", "w") as outfile:
#     csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile)
#     prev = ''
#     csv_writer.writerow(['ID', 'PARENT_ID'])
#     for line in infile.read().splitlines():
#         csv_writer.writerow([line, prev])
#         prev = line

# Method 2
# import numpy as np
# filename = 'RP.dat'
# indata = np.loadtxt(filename)
# print(indata)

# Method 3
with open("RP.dat") as infile:
    file_contents = infile.readlines()
print(file_contents)

C:\Users\benjy\Workspace\urop>python read_dat.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benjy\Workspace\urop\read_dat.py", line 17, in <module>
    file_contents = infile.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\benjy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 672: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use codecs library

```
import codecs  
with codecs.open('RP.dat', errors='ignore', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    dat = f.read()
```